# ARD00280 Microchip Energy Reference Schematic Live and Neutral Swapped?

Tags: power, energy

Looking at the [Microchip Energy Chip reference design](http://www.microchip.com/Microchip.WWW.SecureSoftwareList/secsoftwaredownload.aspx?device=en550354&lang=en&ReturnURL=http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en550354#)

I noticed that the power is being sampled from neutral.  My first reaction to this was this is backwards, that the power should be sampled from the live. however, the guide talks about the concept of a live or hot ground.  what is the advantage of using a hot or live ground as the ground reference in such a design as opposed to sampling from live?

Answer (score 1):

The current shunt of an electricity meter is in the live conductor.  This means the low voltage circuit reference is the live conductor.

The voltage circuit of the meter is as you explain connected between the live and neutral circuits, with the volt drop resistor connected to the neutral circuit.

All shunt electricity meters use this principal.  They are safe because the are double insulated as indicated by the \$\ {\LARGE\square}\hspace -2.2ex {^\square}\ \ \$ symbol on the faceplate.

Answer (score -1):

In my honest opinion this is a very unsafe circuit, it would certainly break electrical safety regulations.  E.g. the push buttons are at live potential!

It is common, certainly in Europe, for the Neutral to be at earth potential.  So connecting your circuit to Neutral and sensing the live is safer than the opposite way round.

The schematic uses a reactive dropper (a potential divider using capacitors) to power itself.  This could work either way round.

The reason for the hot live is that the chip is therefore floating at AC live potential, it simply makes the circuit less costly.  To do the other would mean isolating the chip from the mains which would add components and cost.

The downside is that this means the pushbuttons which are connected to the chip are live - not good.

Comment: If user-interface components which carry mains voltage scare you, I would hate to see your reaction to a common light-switch.

Comment: Anyways, as long as the push-buttons are constructed to make it basically impossible to actually contact any of the switched circuit, it can be perfectly safe.

Comment: In this particular demo circuit, they are using a plastic plunger, that pushes a typical SMT tact switch. As such, you always have ~1 cm of plastic between you and the mains voltage.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Because you're clearly and blatantly incorrect about the safety of the circuit. Your argument is equally valid when applied to any light-switch. It carries mains power, and is connected in series with the hot line.

Comment: Any light switch has an Earth terminal that must be connected to earth.  This circuit has 'GNDB' nodes are are actually live.  I am sure a competent engineer would recognise this, but this is a published circuit, any amature could build it without realising the danger.

Comment: There are no warnings on the PCB or in the schematic. It even points out that connecting the DC power is bad (again safety fail) You state youself that the needs to be a plunger to provide isolation, no mention of that in the schemaic. I stand by my statement on several counts.  Clearly we are going to disagree, I suggest we seek independent input from an expert on IEC60950 and IEC60335

Comment: Are we looking at different things? Giant text right in the middle of the PCB: "DANGER CONNECTING TO J1, P1, J2, OR TP1 MAY CAUSE EXTERNAL EQUIPMENT DAMAGE OR SHOCK HAZARD" "DANGER HIGH VOLTAGE", complete with the little lightning bolt in a triangle symbol. The "DANGER HIGH VOLTAGE" notice is on both sides of the PCB too.

Comment: Furthermore, **it's a reference design, not a final product**. It's not like this is going to be sold to consumers anyways.

Comment: "+9V DC Power In (DO NOT USE WHILE METER IS CONNECTED TO MAINS!)" "DB-9 Connector (NON-ISOLATED)"

Comment: You seem to be conflating documentation meant for a system integration engineer (who is expected to have knowledge of mains safety) and consumer documentation (which this is most definitely not).

Comment: Anyways, I'm actually in the process of designing a similar (different parts, but same concept) power meter like this one, and as part of that I have purchased and taken apart a number of similar devices on the market for research. I can tell you from that that the safety measures taken in this microchip demo design are very much in line with the safety measures taken in similar products that are on the market right now.

Comment: The one thing that I am still curious about is why the design local "ground" is referenced to the hot line. Microchip is not the only group that uses hot as the local "ground" (several eval designs from Cirrus are the same), so I think there is probably *some* reason, but I've yet to see any documentation on it. I suppose it could be a "everyone else does it that way" thing, but that seems unlikely to me. The power meter I'm working on uses neutral as it's local "ground", for the reasons you describe (e.g. safety). We'll see how it works out (the prototype is working, in any event).

Comment: @ConnorWolf a bit late but: did you ever get an answer as you why they do it? The datasheet says for "noise immunity". However, not all manufacturers do this; specially those with metering ICs with isolated ADCs. Check the ADE7913; only the analog ground is live referenced (for obvious reasons) whereas the digital ground is supposed to be floating.

Comment: @AdilMalik - I'm afraid not. All I have is the guesswork above.